# Chrysler money factor

Tags: auto-leasing

Are Chrysler dealers allowed to negotiate the money factor on a lease deal? I want to negotiate a lease deal so I need to know how hard to push on the capitalized cost.

Answer (score 0):

The "money factor" is essentially just the effective interest rate of the lease divided by 2400 (e.g. a 12% lease would have a money factor of 0.005). My guess for this convention is so that it's not directly comparable to what interest rate you would pay for a loan instead.

The rate is largely determined by your credit score and market interest rates for car loans, and may not be negotiable. Many dealers will actually sell the lease to be packaged into securitized bonds (analogous to "mortgage bonds" that consist of thousands of mortgages). So there may not be much room (if any) to negotiate the factor.

I would instead do the same thing you'd do if you were buying the car with a loan - negotiate the *price* , not the interest rate. That will still reduce how much you pay for the car overall and is more transparent to negotiate.